# Recursive definitions - cannot figure this one out

Tags: recurrence-relations

I need to find a recursive solution to the below problem.

$$a_n=n(n-1)$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Calculating some values gives

\begin{align*}
a_1&= 1\cdot (0)=0\\
a_2&= 2\cdot (2-1)=2\\
a_3&= 3\cdot(3-1)=6\\
a_4&= 4\cdot (4-1)=12\\
a_5&= 5\cdot(5-1)=20\\
a_6&= 6\cdot(6-1)=30
\end{align*}

I came up with $a_n=a_{n-1} + 2\cdot(n-1)$. This seems to work for all values. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you want to figure out?

Comment: You're looking for a recurrence relation that defines $a_n$, like $a_{n+1} = 2n + a_n$, $a_1 = 0$?

Comment: his profile says he was not seen for  past 28 minutes ago but this question was asked  21 minutes ago .contradiction.But anyway down voting doesn't make sense . may be he is new and doesn't know to edit .

Comment: This. I also wasn't able to get back online until today. Updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the recurrence relation is not unique.
You can easily write

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=n(n+1)-n(n-1) = 2n,$$
resulting in the $a_{n+1}=a_n+2n$, $a_1=0$ as you have already established.

On the other hand, you can write a second order relation, because
$$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_n = (n+1)(n+2)-2n(n+1)+n(n-1) = 2,$$
giving us a scheme $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}-a_n+2$, $a_1=0$, $a_2 = 2$.

Furthermore, you can continue and obtain a homogeneous relation of third order (hint: take a look at $a_{n+3}-3a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}-a_n$; as bonus, you can make a hypothesis why we take binomial coefficients here), which, given correct initial values, would produce the necessary sequence.